# multiple cpu usage when accessing data attached to traited classes

Tags: python, traits, enthought

I have an application that uses a number of classes inheriting from `HasTraits`. Some of these classes manage access to data and others provide functions for analyzing that data. This works wonderfully for a gui -- I can check that the data and analysis code is doing what it should. However, I've noticed that when I use these classes for gui-less computations, all the cpus on the system end up getting used.

Here is a small example that shows the cpu usage:

```py
from traits.api import HasTraits, List, Int, Enum, Instance
import numpy as np
import psutil
from itertools import combinations

"""
Small example of high CPU usage by traited classes
"""

class DataStorage(HasTraits):
    nsamples = Int(2000)
    samples  = List

    def _samples_default(self):
        return np.random.randn(self.nsamples,2000).tolist()

    def sample_samples(self,indices):
        """ return a 2D array of data at indices """
        return np.array(
                [self.samples[i] for i in indices])

class DataAccessor(HasTraits):
    """ Class that grabs data and computes something """
    measure = Enum("correlation","covariance")
    data_source = Instance(DataStorage,())

    def compute_measure(self,indices):
        """ example of some computation """
        samples = self.data_source.sample_samples(indices)
        percentage = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=0, percpu=True)
        if self.measure == "correlation":
            result = np.corrcoef(samples)
        elif self.measure == "covariance":
            result = np.cov(samples)
        return percentage

# Run a simulation to see cpu usage
analyzer = DataAccessor()
usage = []
n_iterations = 0
max_iterations = 500
for combo in combinations(np.arange(2000),500):
    # evaluate the measurement on a subset of the data
    usage.append(analyzer.compute_measure(combo))
    n_iterations += 1
    if n_iterations > max_iterations:
        break
    print n_iterations

use_percents = np.array(usage).T
```

When I run this on an 8-cpu machine running CentOS, `top` reports the python process at roughly 600%.

```
>>> use_percents.mean(1)
```

shows

```
array([ 67.05548902,  67.06906188,  66.89041916,  67.28942116,
        66.69421158,  67.61437126,  99.8007984 ,  67.31996008])
```

### Question:

My computation is embarrassingly parallel, so it would be great to have the other cpus available to split up the job. Does anyone know what's happening here? A plain python version of this uses 100% on a single cpu.

Is there a way to keep everything local to a single cpu without rewriting all my classes without traits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traits is not causing the CPU usage. It's easy to rewrite this bit of code without Traits, and you will see that you get the same pattern of CPU usage (at least, I do).

Instead, what you are probably seeing is the CPU usage of the BLAS library that your build of numpy is linked against. `numpy.corrcoeff()` calls `numpy.cov()`, and much of the computation of `numpy.cov()` is taken up by a `numpy.dot()` call, which does a matrix-matrix multiplication using BLAS. If it is an optimized BLAS library, then it will usually use non-Python threads internally to split up these computations among your CPUs. You will have to consult the documentation of your optimized BLAS library to find out how to change this.

Comment: I hadn't even thought numpy might be behind this, but you are absolutely correct. Setting MKL_NUM_THREADS=1 solves my problem. Thank you!